# Using Key Value Pair in Jenkins along with parameter editable option

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This is my requirement to have parameters(Which should be editable after auto displayed) in Jenkins:

1. User selects 3 Values from Components: DEV, QA, PROD
2. Upon selection I need to return single or multiple values as parameter as like this:
   If DEV selected, return "Development http://dev.com 1" and "Development http://dev1.com 2"
   If QA selected, return "QA http://qa.com 1" and "QA http://qa.com 2" and "http://qa.com 3"
   If PROD selected, return "Production http://prod.com 1"
3. Once the value is returned in a variable, I will use that variable values in next step of 'Jenkins build'

NOTE: Which ever it returned the above values, it should be editable also

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of parameters.

I would do it this way...

Active Choices https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice
Say call it whatever e.g. MY_PARAM.

Then using the extended choice plugin add a script like...

if (MY_PARAM.equals("Dev")) {return ['Development http://dev.com 1, 'Development http://dev1.com 2']}
else if (MY_PARAM.equals("QA")) {return ['QA http://qa.com 1', 'QA http://qa.com 2', "QA http://qa.com 3"]}
else if (MY_PARAM.equals("PROD")) {return ['Production http://prod.com 1']}

You can then pass down name of the variable to other parts of the build. If cloudbees version you might need to pass a hidden parameter.